# Why is my SwiftUI VStack not aligning properly?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make my VStack padding consistent regardless of the content, and it doesn't seem to be working in certain instances (as if the Scrollview aligned with the center instead).

Ideally, I would like the padding to be consistent regardless of the content on the screen.

Such as this (when padding isn't consistent):

[image: Padding]

[image: Padding 2]

Here is the code used:

```
var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack{
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.backward")
                 
                }
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                      
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack{
                    
                    HStack{
                        
                        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                            
                            Text("Today's Poem, \(currentDate)")
                               
                            
                            if let poem = fetch.poems.first {
                                
                                Text("\(poem.title)")
                                   
                                
                                Text("BY "+poem.author.uppercased())
                                   
                                
                                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                                    
                                    ForEach(poem.lines, id: \.self) {
                                        Text($0)
                                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                         
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                            
                                                        
                            } else {
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            Button("Get Next Poem") { fetch.getPoem() }
            
        }
        .background(Color.white.ignoresSafeArea())
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the innermost

```
VStack {
```

to

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's better, (as in more consistent) but still seems to be thrown off in certain instances. Most of the time when the Title is 2 lines or more. Any ideas why?

Comment: ** Edit, the alignment now works but the padding is what is still inconsistent.

Comment: I would add .lineSpacing(0) to your title, and I assume you want a spacing of 5 for the actual poem text, in which case you should also add that to the innermost VStack. Good luck with your project!

Comment: (1) You shouldn't accept an answer if it didn't fully answer your question, (2) when facing problems like this, the easiest way to debug is to add .background(Color.__) to all of your Stacks and you will see where the edges of the frames do not line up. (3) In your code, you haven't set the alignment for nearly any of the Stacks or the frames. I would guess adding **.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)** to your VStack will solve many of your problems.